# JButtons in GridLayout get resized from a certain aspect ratio

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am building a Minesweeper clone, and my `startNewGame()` method works well. In that method, I also change the field size if the difficulty has been changed.

Here is how it looks on
[easy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDHyH.png) (9x9):

And here is how it looks on [intermediate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb4T4.png) (16x16).

It also works well if I have 20x20, 30x30, etc. The problem is that if I change the board to 30x16 (expert), it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XwDG.png). It seems like it starts stretching the buttons after a certain aspect ratio for some reason. I set the minefield JPanel's preferred size to [16 * x, 16 * y] (each cell is 16x16).

Why are my buttons stretching and how can I prevent that from happening?

Here is my `startNewGame()` method (keep in mind that most things are static so their declarations aren't here):

```
public static void startNewGame()
// Resets and starts a new Game.
{
    timer.stop();
    timerLabel.setText("00:00");
    clicks = 0;

    int newGridLength, newGridHeight, newNumOfMines;
    
    if (difficulties[0].isSelected())
    {
        newGridLength = 9;
        newGridHeight = 9;
        newNumOfMines = 10;
    }
    else if (difficulties[1].isSelected())
    {
        newGridLength = 16;
        newGridHeight = 16;
        newNumOfMines = 40;
    }
    else if (difficulties[2].isSelected())
    {
        newGridLength = 30;
        newGridHeight = 16;
        newNumOfMines = 99;
    }
    else
    {
        newGridLength = 9;
        newGridHeight = 9;
        newNumOfMines = 10;
    }
     
    GRID_LENGTH = newGridLength;
    GRID_HEIGHT = newGridHeight;
    NUM_OF_MINES = newNumOfMines;
 
    remainingMines = NUM_OF_MINES;
    remainingMinesLabel.setText("" + remainingMines);
  
    buttonGrid.clear();
    cellGrid.clear();
  
    frame.remove(gridPane);
    gridPane = new JPanel();
    gridPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(GRID_LENGTH, GRID_HEIGHT));
    initializeGrid(gridPane);
    gridPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CELL_SIZE * GRID_LENGTH, CELL_SIZE * GRID_HEIGHT));
    frame.add(gridPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: If you want your JButtons to be the same size for easy, medium, and hard, you'll have to define a easy, medium, and hard preferred size for the JPanel holding the JButtons.  My [Minesweeper project](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/minesweeper) has a more complete explanation.

Comment: Your take on it is interesting, but I would like to keep my Minesweeper as close as possible to the original. In the original the frame changes size based on the number of rows and columns. Currently I have that too, I just don’t know why it doesn’t work with 30x16.

Comment: *"Your take on it is interesting.."*  Mine? When can we see that SSCCE / MRE? Tip: Add @GilbertLeBlanc (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, I meant GilbertLeBlanc. I was going to add an SSCCE but then I managed to solve it. Thanks for your tips though.

Answer (score 0):

I read more into other layouts and converted my program to `GridBagLayout`, and it's working as intended now.

Result:
[Expert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ooE.png) (30x16)

Comment: `GridLayout` would be easier.

Comment: I did use `GridLayout`, that was the thing that caused me trouble.

Comment: You are using GridLayout incorrectly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(GRID_LENGTH, GRID_HEIGHT));
```

The GridLayout uses

```
new GridLayout(rows, columns)
```

as the parameters.

You are passing the parameters in the wrong order.

Note the easiest to create a GridLayout is to only specify a single non-zero value.

So I would use:

```
gridPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, GRID_LENGTH));
```

This will specify 30 columns.

Now as you add components to the grid it will wrap every 30 components.